# Trouble checking out from a git repo

Tags: git

I'm using Git 1.7.4.1 on Mac 10.6.6.  I'm trying to check out the latest version of our project into an empty directory I have locally.  But this is failing ...

```
davea-mbp2:workspace-sts-2.6.0.SR1 davea$ mkdir systems
davea-mbp2:workspace-sts-2.6.0.SR1 davea$ cd systems/
davea-mbp2:systems davea$ git clone http://dalvarado@mdomain.com/systems.git
Cloning into systems...
Password: 
remote: Counting objects: 1710, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (863/863), done.
remote: Total 1710 (delta 627), reused 592 (delta 260)
Receiving objects: 100% (1710/1710), 30.64 MiB | 6.41 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (627/627), done.
warning: remote HEAD refers to nonexistent ref, unable to checkout
```

After this there is nothing checked out from the remote repo.  I've confirmed the URL and my credentials are correct.  What is the correct way to checkout from a git repo? - Dave

Comment: It is the remote repository that is causing the problem. Someone that has *local* access to the remote repository should do something like `git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/<name-of-some-existing-branch>` so that future clones automatically check out a branch. To use your cloned-but-not-checked-out repository, do `git branch -r` to list the remote tracking branches that have been downloaded, pick one, then check it out with `git checkout -t origin/<some-branch>`.

Answer (score 4):

You have a clone. You have no checkouts. git branch or git tag might suggest some possible things to checkout.

Running clone gets you a complete copy of the upstream repo. By default, the command then checks out the remote HEAD. If, as in this case, the remote HEAD doesn't point to anything, then nothing gets checked out.

What you have done *is* the correct way to clone and checkout a normal repo. Unfortunately, your target is unusual. Someone will have to tell you what branch or tag to check out to get some work done, or you could, as above, run `git branch` or `git tag` to see what's in your clone.

Comment: `for-each-ref` and `ls-remote` might come in handy, too.